# how to get Sound when app is downloaded in android

Tags: android, notifications

I want to hear some sound when app is downloading in android phone.

When i downloaded an application from android market through web i want to hear some siren sound. Can anyone suggest me how can i got this?

Thanks in advance

```
SoundActivity.java
------------------

    public class SoundActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
          if("android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()))
          {
              String PATH_TO_FILE = "/mnt/sdcard/MLKDream_64kb.mp3"; 
            //   MediaPlayer player=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sirensound);
                  MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
                  try {
                      Log.v("play mpe","play mpe");
                       player.setDataSource(PATH_TO_FILE);
                       player.prepare();
                       player.start();
                 } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                 }
          }

Manifest.xml
-------------
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sound"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <receiver 
        android:name=".SoundActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>

    </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe there is a broadcast form the system when the download is finished, just make an app which recived that and play a sound if the broadcast arrived.

like this:

```
public class DownloadChecker extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
      if("android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction()))
      {
         //play a sound here 
      }
    }
```

}

try it with this in the `Manifast.xml` inside the `application` tag

```
<receiver 
        android:name=".DownloadChecker "
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
```

i hope that works, i was not able to test it

Comment: Thanks mr.Boe_dov look at my edits i follow as u said but it is not working can i know where i done mistake

Comment: i looks good for me, strange. I will test in on my own pc soon and give u an awnser

Comment: ok...mr.Bov-dov see this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379003/want-to-have-sound-when-the-app-is-installed) some user posted his problem similar to my problem